# iOS Parse User Information from Google + OAuth Data

Tags: ios, google-oauth

I am attempting to use Google's OAuth services for iOS and am passing the following scopes into the auth mechanism:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

As far as I can tell the login is working correctly (I am prompted for my Google credentials); I can parse out my email from the `GTMOAuth2Authentication` object, but my question is, how do I get the data from "userinfo.profile", i.e., Name, Gender, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the access token to acquire the user's basic profile information by calling the UserInfo endpoint.

See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall